# How to create a npm init script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

according to the [npm-docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-init) the `npm init` command can be used in conjunction with an init-script that would preconfigure a new package:

`npm init <package>`

where `<package>` refers to a package called `create-<package>`. I would like to create such a `create-<package>`-thing, but npm is for some reason trying to execute my create-script with Microsoft JScript instead of node .

I have the following test-structure:

- root-folder

  - client-package
  - create-my-app
    -index.js
    -package.json

`client-package` is the package that I want to initialize using `npm init my-app`.

`create-my-app` is the package that is supposed to contain the create-script. I've linked `create-my-app` to `client-package` using `npm link create-my-app` inside of `client-package`

When I call `npm init my-app` in `client-package` npm locates the `index.js` in `create-my-app` and tries to execute it. But it does not execute it with node, instead it tries to execute it as a windows JScript... whatever that is... How can I tell npm that this is supposed to run with node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is intended to be executed by Node you should indicate it with the proper shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

With that line, we are executing with a Node interpreter, using the env program search path to find it.